# Should OP's be allowed to see deleted answers on questions they've asked and should this answer be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I'm going through one of the bounty questions, [Why is my neural network not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843361/1860929), where the OP is asking why their neural network is not working as per the tutorial followed.

It has an answer by a low rep user, which is right now deleted due to moderator action. While it is not a complete answer in itself, it points the OP in valid directions, which the OP acknowledges within comments. There are some good comments  below the answer, which can be edited into the answer making it more detailed and credible.

Given that the OP is a low rep user and can not see the original answer again, could this answer be undeleted? (I can't vote to undelete since this was mod deleted). The comments hold substantial context for future answerers and OP.

In general, would it be a good idea to let OP's see deleted answers on questions they've asked? At least during the bounty period? :)

Comment: _"Users without enough rep to comment should not write comments as answers. Earn enough rep, then you can comment. Trying to cheat the system may result in a ban."_

Comment: @Cerbrus Hmm I understand the policy, but there was significant discussion in the deleted answer that IMO might've been of value for OP. Have edited the question to reflect that :)

Comment: So? Comments under a not-answer don 't suddenly make the not-answer an answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus _would it be a good idea to let OP's see deleted answers on questions they've asked? At least during the bounty period?_

Comment: You asked: _"could this answer be undeleted?"_. To which I say: Nope.

Comment: @Cerbrus There are 2 questions :)

Comment: He apologized for posting an answer.  Fatal mistake if your posts get reviewed, the reviewers will latch on that instantly.  Given that the post has a bounty, no other answers and discusses a topic that is largely a black art with no obvious correlation between approach and result, a "try this" answer doesn't exactly have to be deleted.  If the chain of comments produces a good outcome then he can edit them into his answer.

Comment: That's definitely an answer.  Edited, and flagged for undelete.